# Proving dimension of a subspace of $F^\infty$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $U=\{(x_{0},x_{1},x_{2},...)\in F^\infty:x_{2k}=x_{0},x_{2k+1}=x_1\}$. Intuitively, the dimension should be two, since the space is uniquely defined by two values. How can I prove this?

Comment: $\{(0,1,0,1...), (1,0,1,0,...)\}$ is a basis.

Comment: @Alex D The definition of $U$ is poorly written, as one gathers from the above that you mean to refer to the subspace:
$U=\left\{x \in K^{\mathbb{N}} \mid (\forall n)\left((n \in 2\mathbb{N} \Rightarrow x_n=x_0) \wedge (n \in 2\mathbb{N}+1 \Rightarrow x_n=x_1)\right)\right\}$. In that case it is easy to show that the vectors $a=\left(2\mathbb{N} \times \{1\}\right) \cup \left(\left(2\mathbb{N}+1\right) \times \{0\}\right)$ and $b=\left(2\mathbb{N} \times \{0\}\right) \cup \left(\left(2\mathbb{N}+1\right) \times \{1\}\right)$ form a basis, as the previous comment indicates.